# Not able to find out (out of memory exception) in azure website

Tags: web-applications, out-of-memory, azure-web-app-service

i have a MVC application which is hosted as azure web app. sometimes this application goes down because of memory out of exception, because of this exception site is also get stopped, i am unable to find from where this exception is coming out i have talked to support team and hey said that the issue with the code. they are suggesting to change the platform 64bt.i have no idea to find out the root cause.

Answer (score 3):

> sometimes this application goes down because of memory out of exception

Many factors and conditions can cause the memory issues, such as ***caching large sets of data***, ***concatenating a large number of strings*** and ***leaking native resources*** etc.

[This article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2020006/how-to-troubleshoot-out-of-memory-issues-system-outofmemoryexception-i) explained how to troubleshoot out of memory issues, you can refer to it and check your code to find the possible cause of OutOfMemoryException issue.